# Multiline string background color in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

How do I remove or change the green background from ES6 multiline strings in PhpStorm?

[image: See an example here.]

Comment: Have you looked in "Fonts and Colors" settings section?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, none of them seem to affect the color. I've tried disabling each of them one by one.

Comment: I think I had this problem before with some other syntax element. Don't remember what it was or how/if I solved it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can't varify, as I am currently not at a machine with PHPStorm installed, but i am quite confident it's:

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Code ->    Injected Language Fragment**

Just remove backgrounds color there.

Comment: Thank you, thought it was a Javascript specific option.